# if write 200 in text field I want to print ok in label

Tags: swift

I want to make translation word in Xcode. 
For example, if I write 200 in text field, I want to print ok in label.

```
@IBOutlet weak var textLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var Button: UIButton!

var responseMessages = [200: "OK",
                        403: "Access forbidden",
                        404: "File not found",
                        500: "Internal server error"]

@IBAction func buttonSender(_ sender: Any) {
    textLabel.text = textField.text
}
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete, and probably (as is) dangerous. The variable responseMessages looks good for a Dictionary, but it's not tied to anything! I get that you probably want to (1) have some button tapped, then (2) query the text in textField against the dictionary, and then (3) populate textLabel with the value found in the dictionary. But what have you tried? What if the user wrote "201" or "200: OK" or "Hello World" in textField?

Comment: How I can  tied the responseMessages with textfield ? and How I can show the error massage if the user wrote 201 ?

Comment: The posted answer is a decent start. You might want to do something more though. Assuming you are looking to work with HTTP codes, reconsider alternatives to using a UITextField, which allows pretty much any text. There are other ways to make this tighter, not allowing for things you aren't coding for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question right you just want the value for a key in the dictionary right?

You could do something like this:

```
@IBAction func buttonSender(_ sender: Any) {
    if let i = responseMessages[Int(textField.text)]{
        textLabel.text = i
    }else{
        textLabel.text = "Error: Invalid Number"
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree, this is a good start for the OP. But this doesn't account for "Hello World" or "Ok". These will result in a check for value 0 (or even worse, nil) and if I typed in "Ok" or "OK", because the response was HTTP 200, I'd be confused with the error this generates.